# How to model a transport problem as a flow problem?

Tags: graph-theory

I am working on the fellowing transport problem. Let assume a company want to accomplish daily a number of transports $T_1,\ldots,T_m$ between $n$ cities $C_1,\ldots,C_n$. We know the duration of every transport between every couple of cities for example $d_{i,j}$ the duration of a transport between cities $C_i$ and $C_j$. On the other hand for every transport we know the departure city, the arrival city and the time of departure. The company want to minimize the cost of all transports by using a minimum number of vehicles. How can I formulate this problem of finding the minimum number of vehicles as a problem of flow. I tried to consider a graph where two cities are connected if there exists a transport between them but unfortunately, I did not obtain a model where I can use a flow problem. Does anyone have any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is probably an integer programming problem. The exact form requires a few more specifications, like :

- Whether a vehicle can be affected to several trips, if these trips
  need the same route or if vehicles can transport A->B, then go to C
  and transport C->D.
- Whether a vehicle has to be back to its starting
  point at the end of the day, or to a given warehouse, or not
- Whether you have time constraints (you presumably do)
- etc.

The binary variables will likely include $x_{ij}=1$ if vehicle $i$ does transport $j$ and $=0$ otherwise. It can get quite complex depending on your constraints.

The underlying graph will be relevant but that is only part of the equation.

You may want to google "integer programming for transportation problems", the field is huge and has been researched for at least 30 years. Most of these problems are hard in the sense that obtaining an optimal solution takes a very long time for large $m$ and $n$ (google "NP-Hard").